Want To Create A Keyboard Shortcut To Enter A Text String Into A Field
Simple request: Using the Settings>Keyboard Shortcuts>View And Customize Shortcuts>Custom Shortcuts I want to perform the following. Create a keyboard shortcut (e.g. CTRL r) to enter my email address (e.g. richard@mail.com) into a text field or a field that requires my email address.
I've done quite a bit of Google research and have found no options that work. In addition, I've looked through the "similar questions" section here, tried several, and none work. I've downloaded, installed, and used xdotool and xclip as per some of the suggestions listed and none of the suggestions has worked. Essentially, I place the listed commands (as per the examples--except with my e-mail address) in the Command space of the Custom Shortcut field, press the desired shortcut keys, go back to either a text editor, or to my e-mail app, place the cursor where I want the email address to be entered, press the shortcut key combination (CTRL r), and nothing gets pasted into the field or text app.
I have also tried unsuccessfully, the Input Remapper and AutoKey applications--no success there either.
So, you can imagine I'm at my wit's end and I would very much appreciate help with this.
I'm using a Lenovo Ideapad Z580 with Ubuntu 24.04. The combination works great and I have had zero problems; so, I doubt it's the hardware or software. For more detail, it's a 64-bit machine, Gnome Version 46, Windowing System is Wayland, and the Kernel Version is Linux 6.8.0-41-generic.
Thank you...

Finally! With your information Vanadium, and a fix for ydotool from hrvoj3e on GitHub (https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool/issues/36#issuecomment-624629221) I was able to get ydotool to work exactly as expected.
I installed the ydotool and ydotoold and then applied the fix as provided by hrvoj3e in the above GitHub link. Then I made slight changes to the command you provided--I changed it to: sh -c 'sleep 0.5 ; ydotool type myemail@mail.com'. The changes were to the time of the sleep command from 0.2 to 0.5, and of course I used my own e-mail. Everything is now working like a charm. Thank you much! And thank you hrvoj3e!

xdotool nor xclip work anymore with standard Ubuntu, which runs on Wayland. You can use keyboard automation tools that do not depend on xorg, e.g. dotool or ydotool.

Install dotool (https://git.sr.ht/~geb/dotool). It is a manual compilation, however very easy. Make sure to enable the daemon for performance reasons.

Bind the following command to your preferred shortcut key, using "Settings" - "Keyboard" - "Keyboard Shortcuts" - "Custom shortcuts"
sh -c '{ sleep 0.2 ; echo type myemailadress.com; } | dotoolc'

The sleep command allows you to release your shortcut key (e.g. Ctrl before the daemon sends keystrokes.


If you prefer, you can use ydotool which is included in the Ubuntu software repositories. The command will be
sh -c 'sleep 0.2 ; ydotool type myemailadress.com'

